# Date range picker calendar not appear

Tags: javascript, daterangepicker, bootstrap-daterangepicker

I'm trying to use date range picker but I can't seem to make it work.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap/3/css/bootstrap.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" 
src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.css" />
```

.

```
<input type="text" name="daterange" value="01/01/2015 - 01/31/2015" />

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker();
});
</script>
```

I don't understand why it doesn't show the calendar. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your code works fine, do you see any error in your console ? Did you try to clear your cache ?

Comment: @Reynadan There is an error in console "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).daterangepicker is not a function"

Comment: Maybe you are not placing your scripts in the right order, make sure daterangepicker.js and jquery are included first, before your function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the snippet, just so you know it works

```js
$(function() {
  $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker();
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap/3/css/bootstrap.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" 
src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.css" />

<input type="text" name="daterange" value="01/01/2015 - 01/31/2015" />
```